# Is there an easy way to get Lowpro working with IE9?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, lowpro

We have a lot of legacy code that relies on Lowpro and Prototype. The plan is to port this code into jQuery at some point, but in the mean time, is there an easy way to get these two libraries to work with IE9?

Lowpro appears to only work with Prototype 1.6 (not 1.7), but IE9 appears to only work with Prototype 1.7+

I've tried upgrading these plugins, but nothing seems to work. Is there anything else I can do, save for a complete rewrite?

Comment: Not directly related to the solution of your question, but can you explain why you want to drop Prototype in the near future? jQuery 'looks' fancy, but Prototype ain't a bad framework at all.

Comment: A couple reasons. First, it looks like Prototype has been abandoned (the last release was over a year ago) and Rails has already made the switch to jQuery. Second, jQuery is faster and more popular. jQuery's popularity means it's going to get easier and easier to find new developers who are comfortable with jQuery and harder and harder to find developers who are good with Prototype.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm wondering also whether to drop Prototype, but overall.. Prototype does still anything I want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late now but incase someone else is looking - there is an forked version on github with Prototype 1.7 compatibility:

https://github.com/dwg/low-pro

https://raw.github.com/dwg/low-pro/master/dist/lowpro.js